# Preceding sibling in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to put a specific condition on the basis of preceding sibling check.
I tried various options but nothing worked.
Here is the sample XML

```
<abc>
 <title>something</title>
 <element>1</element>
 <element>2</element>
 <element>3</element>
 <element>4</element>    
</abc>
```

I have a template match for `<element>`  tag and I want to check if its immediate element is `<title>` Do some additioanl processing else do some other processing. Any pointers appriciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 4):

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    I am boring. <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]">
    I am special. <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the current context is an `element` element then you can get its nearest preceding sibling element (regardless of name) using

```
preceding-sibling::*[1]
```

and so to check whether that element is a `title` you can use

```
preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="element[preceding-sibling::element()[1][self::title]]"/>
```

Comment: This is correct for XSLT 2.0, if you're using 1.0 then you must use `*` instead of `element()`.